# horizontally scroll to nth-child element position

Tags: javascript

I am working on a responsive tab menu with a scrolling js effect.

I saw that most of the tab menu on mobile is horizontal scroll. When I click `<li>` elements on tab menu, `<ul>` scroll little to `<li>` position, but because many websites use `sliderjs` in my Country, I think it is not good enough and definitely heavy to use `sliderjs` to tab menu.

So, I try to  work on

1. get each `<li>` elements' position,
2. scrolling event when click `<li>` elements
3. combine  1) and 2).

I think there is some issue with my code below :

1. I tried to get the relative of each child's position by subtracting those from their parent but when I put the `scrolledChildsDistance` all childs' position appeared as same.
2. on the scroll function, I would like the `<nav>` scroll to not only left but also automatically right move if the `<li>` is front.

```js
  const tabWrap = document.querySelector('.namsaService_tabContainer')
        const tabList = document.querySelectorAll('.namsaService_tabList')

        //get the relative X position of tabList[i] (the start horizontal point of each tabList)
        for (i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
            var parentPos = tabWrap.offsetLeft; //get parent position (tabWrap)
            var childPos = tabList[i].getBoundingClientRect().left; //get child position (tabList[i])
            var scrolledChildsDistance = Math.abs(childPos - parentPos); //get relative each child positions by substract those from their parent
            console.log(scrolledChildsDistance)
            // console.log(childPos)

            tabList[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) { //when click tabList[i], tabWrap scroll to targeted tabList left position
                e.preventDefault();
                tabWrap.scrollBy({
                    top: 0,
                    left: childPos - parentPos,
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                });
            });
        }
```

```css
 /*::: NAMSA SERVICE TAB :::*/
 
   .namsaService_tabContainer {
            width: 800px; 
            overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            .namsaService_tab {
                width: 800px; 
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        .namsaService_tab:after {
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #ddd;
            display: block;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 21px;
            color: #888;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList::after {
            content: "";
            background-color: #125687;
            height: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            transition: .16s all 0.025s;
            display: block;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList.on::after {
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList::after {
            left: 100%;
            right: 0;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList:hover~.namsaService_tabList::after {
            left: 0;
            right: 100%;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList:hover::after {
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList.on {
            color: #222;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .namsaService_tabList+.namsaService_tabList {
            margin-left: 80px;
        }

        /* ::: RESPONISUIVE @media :::*/

        @media (max-width: 1200px) {

            /* ::: TITLE ~ COUNTER VISUAL ::: */
            .namsaService_Bold br {
                display: none;
            }

            /* ::: TAB ::: */
            .namsaService_tabList+.namsaService_tabList {
                margin-left: 30px;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 991px) {

            /* ::: VISUAL ::: */
            .subVisual {
                height: 250px;
            }

            .subVisual_tit {
                font-size: 40px;
                line-height: 50px;
            }

            .lnbContainer {
                padding-top: 30px;
                padding-bottom: 80px;
            }

            /* ::: TITLE ~ COUNTER VISUAL ::: */
            .lnbContainer_titWrap {
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }

            .namsaService_Bold {
                font-size: 30px;
                line-height: 42px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }

            /* ::: COMMON CARD UI ::: */
            .namsaService_listWrap {
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }

            .namsaService_list {
                width: calc((100% / 2) - 15px);
            }

            .namsaService_list:not(:nth-child(3n)) {
                margin-right: 0;
            }

            .namsaService_list:nth-child(even) {
                margin-left: 30px;
            }

            .namsaService_list:not(:nth-child(n+5)) {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }

            /* ::: TAB ::: */
            .namsaService_tabList {
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            .namsaService_tabList+.namsaService_tabList {
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            
        }

        @media (max-width : 767px) {
            /* ::: TITLE ~ COUNTER VISUAL ::: */

            .namsaService_Bold {
                font-size: 20px;
                line-height: 30px;
                padding-bottom: 30px;
            }

            /* ::: COMMON CARD UI ::: */
            .namsaService_list {
                width: 100%
            }

            .namsaService_list:not(:nth-child(3n)),
            .namsaService_list:nth-child(even) {
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
            }

            .namsaService_list:not(:last-child) {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }

            .namsaService_tit {
                font-size: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .namsaService_desc {
                font-size: 13px;
            }

            /* ::: TAB ::: */
            .namsaService_tabList {
                font-size: 14px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<article class="lnbContainer_contentWrap inr namsaService_tabContainer">
        <nav class="namsaService_tab">
            <ul class="namsaService_tabWrap">
                <li class="namsaService_tabList on">gnb_1 productTest </li>
                <li class="namsaService_tabList">gnb_2 Brand </li>
                <li class="namsaService_tabList"> gnb_3 Portporflio</li>
                <li class="namsaService_tabList"> gnb_4 contact</li>
                <li class="namsaService_tabList"> gnb_5 Inquiries</li>
                <li class="namsaService_tabList"> gnb_6 News</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </article>
```